# Odd visual behavior from ToolStripMenuItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, drop-down-menu

I've got a Drop Down Menu that is dynamically filled every time it opens, here is the logic that does it:

```
private void joysticksToolStripMenuItem_DropDownOpening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _joysticks = _joystickWrapper.FindDevices(DeviceType.Joystick);
    joysticksToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Clear();
    foreach (var di in _joysticks)
    {
        var item = new ToolStripMenuItem(di.ProductName);
        item.Checked = di.InstanceGuid == _joystickWrapper.CurrentDeviceInfo.InstanceGuid;
        joysticksToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
    }
}
```

When I run the application this is what I see:

[image: That cant be right...]

The check is in the wrong location and the blue area is too wide.

Any ideas on where to look to fix this? The entire menu is all `System.Windows.Forms`, no custom visual code in the entire application.

I tried on my current machine (Windows 10 Build 9926) and on my dev server (Server 2012R2) with the same results. I've also compiled this to the NET Framework 4.5 and 4.5.1

**EDIT**

For those interested, here is the git repo for this project:

https://github.com/adam8797/RovControl

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue on my Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks for taking the time to test for me. Would it be helpful to post the git repo for the project?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue currently.

Comment: @DanielSimpkins Nope. Just had to live with it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I came across this exact same issue and was finally able to resolve it by setting the `ImageScalingSize` property of the MenuStrip to `16,16` (it had somehow been set to 32,32, possibly due to my editing of the form on a high DPI machine)

Comment: You know I almost forgot about this question completely, but the same issue actually just came up again for me in a different project! Your fix worked like a charm.

Comment: .ImageScaling = ToolStripItemImageScaling.None resolved it for me.  thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 0):

I see you adding items in Menu while its opening. Seems like the selected area and its width is already defined and its not reacting to the new data you inserted. What about trying to manually define width of Menu Item and see if that helps.

Comment: No dice. Its actually not even letting me modify `item.Width` or `item.Height`. I change them but it is not reflected visually.

Comment: What about keeping the design time width to a higher side?

Comment: I should of mentioned, I set the width to 600 and there was no visual difference.

Comment: the width of menu item is only to decrease width. to increase the width of a menu item you also have to increase it's parent object width `ToolStripDropDownMenu.Width`.